# Edit named coordinates

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Let's say I read an .xslx file that has a table. And in that table there are let's say `money`, `accounts` and `cars` as coordinates Y and `week1`, `week2` and `week3` as coordinates X. Let's say I use passing arguments from the command line using coordinates like java myprogram `cars` `week2` so I want to add 1 to that cell.

What is the best approach to solve this?
Do I have to read the table?
Can I find the row using something similar to?:

```
if 
sheet.contains("accounts" and "week2")
add number
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Which tutorials are you following?

Comment: I'm trying to loop for every cell that contains a header word from the table and then I use getrownum() and getcolumnindex